# Adding panels to JScroll

Tags: java, swing

I have made an application that has 3 panels. A status, btn and top panel. I have some buttons added to the btn panel and some labels in the status panel and some text fields in the top panel. All of these panels are added to a JFrame. I wanted to put all of this into a JScroller. I am unsure on how to do this, any help is appreciated. I added some code showing how I laid everything out.

```
static FlowLayout topPanelLayout = new FlowLayout();
static GridLayout parentLayout = new GridLayout(0,1);
static GridLayout statusLayout = new GridLayout(2,1);
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Web API Interface");
static JPanel statusPanel;
static JPanel btnPanel;
static JPanel topPanel;       frame.setLayout(parentLayout);

    // -- Create Panels
    topPanel = new JPanel(topPanelLayout);
    statusPanel = new JPanel(statusLayout);
    btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));

    frame.setSize(1100,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); statusPanel.add(statusLabel);
    statusPanel.add(connectionStatusLabel);
    statusPanel.add(cidLabel);

    // -- add label and textfield at the top panel which is at the top of
    //    the frame
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter IP:"));
    topPanel.add(ipAddressField);



    // -- 1.) add top panel .... everything goes in order down
    frame.getContentPane().add(topPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(statusPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnPanel);
    //Display the window.
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> JScroller

What is a JScroller??? Use proper class names so we know exactly what you are talking about.

Don't add the 3 panels to the frame.

Instead you add the 3 panel to another panel. Then you create a `JScrollPane` using that panel and finally you add the scroll pane to the frame:

```
//frame.getContentPane().add(topPanel);
//frame.getContentPane().add(statusPanel);
//frame.getContentPane().add(btnPanel);
JPanel parent = new JPanel( parentLayout );
parent.add( topPanel );
parent.add( statusPanel );
parent.add( btnPanel );
frame.add( new JScrollPane( parent ) );
```

Also, get rid of all the static variables. There is no need for the variables to be static if the code is designed properly.